Accessing Audio Input Data from a USB Microphone (MiniDSP UMIK-1) in Golang
I'm planning to develop a program in Golang to access audio input data from a USB microphone, specifically the MiniDSP UMIK-1. This microphone uses USB Audio Class 1, and I aim to find a library that allows me to easily read information such as the current frequency of the input signal.
So far, I have found a low-level USB library (gousb), but I am wondering if there are any libraries better suited for my needs.
As I have not yet received the microphone, I haven't been able to conduct any tests. Are there any recommended libraries or approaches for handling USB audio input in Golang that would be more suitable than using a low-level USB library? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
